# ubuntu 20.04 ターミナルで特定コマンドの出力のみ文字化けする

Tags: macos, ubuntu, zsh, unicode

ubuntu20.04 サーバに、MacOS BigSur から iterm2 を利用してssh接続しています。

この状態で、「一部のコマンドの出力のみ」文字化けする症状に悩んでいます。

具体的には ls コマンドなのですが、

```
$ ls

 test  ''$'\343\203\206\343\202\271\343\203\210'
```

不思議なことに、この出力を他のコマンドにパイプすると、文字化けは起こりません。

```
$ ls | cat

test
テスト
```

サーバは多国籍なチームが触りますので、`LANG=en_US.UTF-8` に設定してあります。
しかし、下記のようにLANG変数を設定してからでも、挙動は変わりませんでした。

```
$ LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 ls

 test  ''$'\343\203\206\343\202\271\343\203\210'
```

cat コマンドについては、日本語のファイルも正しく表示出来るのですが、

```
$ cat README.md

* 研究室内部開発用
...
```

nano コマンドでは日本語が全ておかしな表示になります。

```
$ nano README.md

    ^t                     ^f^e   ^c      ^v^k   ^y      ^t
...
```

vi コマンドではまた化け方が異なり、一部の日本語文字が見える状態になります。

```
$ vi README.md

~T究室�~F~E�~C��~V~K�~Y��~T�
...
```

非常に珍しい症状で対応に悩んでいるのですが、
これらの異なる表示となるコマンド群の設定を統一して、
常に日本語が正しく表示される状態にする方法はありませんでしょうか？

ファイルの中身とファイル名は、全てUTF-8のみを使用しています。
マシンは、LinuxとMacのみが存在する環境です。

## 追記

追加でいくつか検証を行いました

・MacOS 標準の terminal.app でも全く同じ症状
iterm2 固有の症状では無いようです

・追加した exa コマンド等も文字化けしない
OS標準の ls コマンドや nano と、exa や catは なにか異なる設定を読み込んでいる？

・locale コマンドの出力にエラーが出ている

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: lsはエイリアスになっていたりしませんか？

Comment: その Ubuntu20.04 サーバがサポートしているロケールに `ja_JP.UTF-8` は含まれているのでしょうか？ `cat /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED | grep 'ja_JP\.UTF-8'` を実行して確認してみてください。

Comment: @Itagaki Fumihiko 
```which ls``` の結果は ```/usr/bin/ls``` でした。OS標準の実行ファイルかと思います

Comment: @metropolis
出力は ```ja_JP.UTF-8 UTF-8```となりました。ロケールはインストールされているようです。

Comment: whilch ls ではなく type ls を調べてください。念のため。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。結果は ```ls is /usr/bin/ls``` となりました

Comment: なるほど、手元の Ubuntu 21.04 でも `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 ls`  とすると "テスト" が octal 表示になります。 LANG よりも LC_CTYPE の設定の方が優先されるのですね。

Comment: itagakiさま、metropolis さま、ご指摘ありがとうございました。頂いたヒントを実行しながら思案し検索した所、無事解決する事が出来ました！

Comment: コマンドによって、参照されるロケール変数が異なるのですね。検証にまでご協力頂いてありがとうございました！ 正直あまりわかっていない分野で、ご指摘ありがたく参考にさせて頂きました

Answer (score 2):

上記 `locale` コマンドのエラーメッセージで検索した所、こちらの記事が見つかりました
https://askubuntu.com/questions/599808/cannot-set-lc-ctype-to-default-locale-no-such-file-or-directory

添付画像のように、iterm2 の、ロケール変数の自動設定をオフにして
iterm2を再起動した所、locale コマンドの結果からエラーが消え、
`ls nano vi` いずれも日本語が正しく表示される用になりました[image: iterm2設定ダイアログ]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]